PlatfomIO platformio/espressif32 6.9.0 reports SDK version 4.4.7-dirty
In trying to move from Arduino IDE to PlatformIO, I'm running into a question with regard to the IDF/SDK version. I'm sure this is a misunderstanding on my part, but platformio/espressif version 6.9.0 seems to be built off of SDK 4.4.7 even though the release notes say it's using version v5.3.1. Am I confused on SDK version vs IDF vs ???
Release notes for version 6.9.0 are here:
https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif32/releases/tag/v6.9.0
6.9.0 Latest
@valeros valeros released this Sep 26
· 7 commits to develop since this release
 v6.9.0
 268f561
Release Notes
Added WeAct Studio ESP32C3CoreBoard board
Added support for ESP-IDF v5.3.1 (release notes)

Result from program below is:
Espressif ESP32 Dev Module
SDK Version: v4.4.7-dirty 
v4.4.7-dirty

I expected the SDK version to say 5.3.1.
My minimal test example:
platformio.ini
monitor_speed = 115200

[env:esp32dev]
platform = platformio/espressif32@^6.9.0
board = esp32dev
framework = arduino

main.cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

void setup() {
   Serial.begin (115200);                           // full speed to monitor
   delay(2000);
   Serial.println ("\n\n\n");
   Serial.println (ARDUINO_BOARD);

   Serial.print ("SDK Version: ");
   Serial.println (ESP.getSdkVersion());
   Serial.println (esp_get_idf_version());

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

And finally, partial output from the compile showing it really took 6.9.0:
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION: https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32dev.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (6.9.0) > Espressif ESP32 Dev Module
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash

As I said, I'm sure this is just a misunderstanding on my part, but I'm not getting it. Things were clearer back when I just stuck the library source into my card deck.
